# The `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` scope requires additional permissions for folder to be provisioned

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

This is an issue I'm seeing for MSAs (Personal OneDrives)

I've created an AAD App registration with the `User.Read` and `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` Graph API permissions. The application is intended to be used to upload scanned documents from a scanner to the user's OneDrive.

I get an `Access Denied` exception when calling the `graphClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(<random filename>).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync()` API. However, if I add the `Files.ReadWrite.All` API permission to the AAD App registration, have a user consent to that permission, upload a file to the app folder, remove the `Files.ReadWrite.All` API permission, and reauthenticate the user, calls to `graphClient.Drive.Special.AppRoot.ItemWithPath(<random filename>).CreateUploadSession().Request().PostAsync()` work as expected.

This seems to be an issue with the initial provision of the app folder.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try by adding Files.ReadWrite permission in place of Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder

[image]

ref doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: I specifically don't want to grant access to the entire drive. `FilesReadWrite`'s description says it will let the application "Have full access to user files." (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/permissions_reference?view=odsp-graph-online)